# Usage of "at least"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Recently I got into a fight with a guy I met while gaming. He was using very inappropriate language, so I said to him, "You must be at least 13 years old to chat like that"

He said that you have to use "must be" instead of "at least" in that type of sentence.

Is it grammatically correct to use at least in this situation?

Comment: Was your purpose to inform him of something or to insult him? Or something else? Could you clarify what was the purpose of your statement?

Comment: @AlanCarmack insult him :p

Comment: Or just say "you talk like a child".

Comment: If you want to sound less formal, you could say: *You've got to be at least 13 to use that kind of language.* I've got to admit though (same usage as the previous sentence meaning must)  that I'm a bit confused by your question since you used both *must be* and *at least* in your example. There's no way around it though, you have got to use *have to be, have got to be,* or *must be* in that sentence; it's not grammatical without it. Also, I could easily swap *have to* with *must* in your 3rd sentence *He said that you, have to [or **must**] use…*  without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he's right. Because the way your original sentence is phrased sounds more like you're allowed to talk like that only when you have reached 13 years of age. Semantically, this would be similar to the way we talk about the right to vote: in the U.S., you must be at least 18 years old before you're given the right to cast your vote in political elections.

So, if you were trying to make it sound more insulting, you should have said the following instead:

> Hey, pal, looking at the way you speak, you must be 13 years old or something.

or:

> Hey, buddy, the way you talk sounds like you're only 13.

Answer (score 1):

Since  you are aiming for an insult,  then your sentence

> You must be at least 13 years old to chat like that

is formatted correctly. Thus insult is more subtle than direct: *at least 13 years old* is used ironically. The  sentence can be used to tell the guy that he is not acting even like a 13-year-old would. In other words the sentence is telling your "opponent" that he's under the age of 13 since he has to be *at least 13 years old to chat in the manner he is chatting*. This is how the sentence can be used as an "insult"; whether that's what you meant is another story.